# When mouse clicking a thumbnail, the thumbnail to the right jumps left

Tags: html, css

This is driving me mad.

As a budding amateur I built a website for a friend and I have an issue.  Take a look at this page...

http://www.frameconservation.co.uk/gilding.htm

There are images here with a caption below.  It all displays how I want but when you click on the left thumbnail, the one to the right jumps to the left.  The linked image opens correctly using Thickbox when you release the mouse button but I can't work out why the thumbnail jumps.

The HTML for the first item looks like this...

```
<ul class="photolistbottomcaption">
    <li><a href="images/gilding/Bracket_before_lg.JPG" class="thickbox" rel="gild5" title="before" ><img src="images/gilding/Bracket_before_sml.JPG" alt="" width="290" height="223" title="before" /></a><strong>before</strong></li>
    <li><a href="images/gilding/Bracket_finished_lg.JPG" class="thickbox" rel="gild5" title="after" ><img src="images/gilding/Bracket_finished_sml.JPG" alt="" width="290" height="223" title="after" /></a><strong>after</strong></li>
</ul>

<div class="clear"></div>
      <br />              
      <p><strong>Brackets</strong><br /><strong>Owner</strong>: Private.<br />Pair of worn grotesque brackets needed new gilding after long term storage in a damp cellar and the inexpert attention of the unqualified removed their original gilding.</p>
      <br />
      <hr />
```

My CSS looks like this

```
.photolistbottomcaption {
    list-style-type: none;
    padding-left: 0;
    margin-left: 0
    }

.photolistbottomcaption a {
    text-decoration: none;
    color: #003D47
    }

.photolistbottomcaption li {
    float: left;
    margin-right: 6px
    }

.photolistbottomcaption img {
    display: block;
    border: 1px solid #333333
    }
```

Happy with the display, just not the fact that the thumbnail to the right jumps to the left.

Any help would be hugely appreciated.

Cheers

Comment: Somewhere there's a rule that sets `display:block` on the `ul a`, causing the after to slide left. use Firebug in FF, toggle the :active rule, then look at the containing `<a>` of the image.

Comment: I think javascript  mouse down.is bind with that element.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is in another part of your CSS (mike.css - Line 115)

```css
#navi ul a, ul a:visited, ul a:active {
    background: none repeat scroll 0 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0);
    color: #663300;
    display: block;
    text-decoration: none;
    width: 196px;
}
```

If you remove `width: 196px;` the picture doesn't jump to the left.

Comment: Thanks so much for your answers.  Maryisdead and Eich you solved it for me.  What confuses me though is that the ul a:active line is part of the #navi div yet it still affects these images which are not contained within the navi div.  Is this something to do with inherited attributes?

Comment: These are 3 different selectors. For each of them the CSS is working. That's because they are comma separated, so ```#navi ul a, ul a:visited, ul a:active``` means ```#navi ul a```, ```ul a:visited``` and ```ul a:active``` are getting the defined styling :)

Comment: Got it! Thanks for the clarification.  Website now fixed and knowledge expanded.  Cheers.

Comment: No problem :) . Please mark an answer as accepted, so that others can see that they don't have to answer anymore :) .

Answer (score 0):

In *mike.css* at line 115 you have this defined:

```css
#navi ul a, ul a:visited, ul a:active {
    text-decoration: none;
    background: none;
    display: block;
    width: 196px;
    color: #663300;
    }
```

The `ul a:active` kicks in when you click the link and sets the width of the link to 196 pixels (which is less than the width of the image within).